# Добавление поиска SearchView в Activity не содержащую ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-search-view

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
я реализовал SearchView в ToolBar, при этом в активности нет элемента ListView. На ней расположены 10 кнопок с картинками. Как сделать чтобы при открытии SearchView кнопки пропадали и появлялся список, по которому производится поиск?

Во многих приложениях при нажатии на SearchView содержимое экрана пропадает, остается только белый фон и на нем сразу отображается ListView по которому идет поиск. Хочу сделать также.

Если вопрос неясен, напишите в комментариях, постараюсь сделать картинки.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем activity переопределите метод onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //R.menu.dashboard поменйте на id своего меню
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

    //R.id.action_search поменйте на id своего searchView
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            //скрываете UI, показываете список с результатами поиска
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            //скрываете список с результатами поиска, показываете UI
            return true;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //производите поиск, обновляете содержимое списка
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

C помощью вышеприведенного кода можно реагировать на открытие/закрытие searchView, а также на ввод в него текста

> Как сделать чтобы при открытии SearchView кнопки пропадали и появлялся список, по которому производится поиск?

это необходимо делать вручную, например так (вариант не оптимальный, но самый понятный).
Поместите в активити список, в котором будете отображать результаты поиска, сделайте его невидимым

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

При открытии searchView делаете список видимым,`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` а все кнопки - невидимыми. Т.е. у всех кнопок надо вызвать

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Ну а при закрытии searchView - делает все наоборот

Comment: Может быть есть второй способ? Этот способ хороший но все таки это костыльная реализация.